# SemVer and GitFlow / How to patch a release

Tags: git, git-flow, release-management, semantic-versioning, semantic-release

We are trying to implement automatic version bumping based on the semver spec... Ideally, we would just merge into master and produce a new version update on the CI.

```
    --------------development branch----
   /                                    \
--/--base branch------------------------v1.1.0------
```

We are not there yet, due to some release cycle's constrains, we are using a gitflow approach:

```
    --------------release branch/v1.1.x----
   /                                    
--/--base branch----v1.2+.x------
```

every time we cut a release branch, and, let's say, we publish a minor/major update, we have to keep that release open to allow for hot fixes (only patches will eventually go on the current release branch)...

**Now, we want to get `semver` to play well with this flow (which we cannot change at the moment).**

how can we make sure that:

1. once we cut a release then the following commit on the base branch will have at least a minor bump?
2. how can we bring the hotfixes on the release branch back into master?

Answer (score 0):

if you use [conventional commits](https://conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0-beta.4/), you can setup automated semver version bumping, releases, and release notes generation with [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release), (Optional) [commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli), (Optional) [commitlint](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint), (Optional) [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky)

Basically master branch can be your release branch, so any commits that land to master will trigger semantic-release, semantic-release will look at all the commits since the last version and see if they require a release/version bump, if they do it will create the release for you.

See for an explanation on how to set this up https://medium.com/faun/automate-your-releases-versioning-and-release-notes-with-semantic-release-d5575b73d986

Comment: we use conventional commits too, the question is not about `how to generate releases or changelogs`, the question is **how to use semver with gitflow?**

Comment: @Hitmands you just ensure that you have one release branch, feature branches get merged in --> You trigger the release and bump the version --> Hotfixes ? --> New patch release.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is to use a *post*-commit prompt script via `husky`. This has a ton of flexibility while reminding your team to keep your versions current.

Below is the script I use.

```
# .husky/_/post-commit
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

echo "Bump that version!"

exec < /dev/tty

PS3='Please enter your bump choice: '
options=("skip" "patch" "minor" "major")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "skip")
            break
            ;;
        "patch")
            break
            ;;
        "minor")
            break
            ;;
        "major")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done

if [[ "$opt" == "skip" ]];
then
    echo "✓ Skipping..."
else
    echo " ✓ Bumping version by $opt"
    yarn standard-version -r $opt
    git push --no-verify --follow-tags origin main
fi
```